# Unused Indexes - PostgreSQL Database

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.5, enterprisedb

I have used attached query to check unused indexes in my EDB9.5 DB. It's showing attached indexes are the unused indexes. Is it safe to drop below unused indexes?

```
SELECT
    idstat.relname AS TABLE_NAME,
    indexrelname AS index_name,
    idstat.idx_scan AS index_scans_count,
    pg_size_pretty(pg_relation_size(indexrelid)) AS index_size,
    tabstat.idx_scan AS table_reads_index_count,
    tabstat.seq_scan AS table_reads_seq_count,
    tabstat.seq_scan + tabstat.idx_scan AS table_reads_count,
    n_tup_upd + n_tup_ins + n_tup_del AS table_writes_count,
    pg_size_pretty(pg_relation_size(idstat.relid)) AS table_size
FROM
    pg_stat_user_indexes AS idstat
JOIN
    pg_indexes
    ON
    indexrelname = indexname
    AND
    idstat.schemaname = pg_indexes.schemaname
JOIN
    pg_stat_user_tables AS tabstat
    ON
    idstat.relid = tabstat.relid
WHERE
    indexdef !~* 'unique'
    and idstat.relname='cwt_act'
ORDER BY
    idstat.idx_scan DESC,
    pg_relation_size(indexrelid) DESC;
```

Please suggest!

Answer (score 4):

You are missing a few points:

- there could be a GiST index supporting an exclusion constraint
- an index on an expression can help the optimizer get better estimates for that expression, even if it isn't scanned

I recommend the query from [my blog](https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/get-rid-of-your-unused-indexes/):

```
SELECT s.schemaname,
       s.relname AS tablename,
       s.indexrelname AS indexname,
       pg_relation_size(s.indexrelid) AS index_size
FROM pg_catalog.pg_stat_user_indexes s
   JOIN pg_catalog.pg_index i ON s.indexrelid = i.indexrelid
WHERE s.idx_scan = 0      -- has never been scanned
  AND 0 <>ALL (i.indkey)  -- no index column is an expression
  AND NOT i.indisunique   -- is not a UNIQUE index
  AND NOT EXISTS          -- does not enforce a constraint
         (SELECT 1 FROM pg_catalog.pg_constraint c
          WHERE c.conindid = s.indexrelid)
ORDER BY pg_relation_size(s.indexrelid) DESC;
```